# Font Awesome icon in ractjs import

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome

I am creating a nnavbar in reactJs for my personal project's website. I have a problem to import the Font Awesome into the navbar. I downloaded all the dependencies an followed the docs, created the config files, but i can't see the icons.
This is the [repo](https://github.com/fedcal/ComputerScienceNotes) there i upload the code. Thanks to all that will help me.

Comment: Since it's a personal project, I would suggest going for https://react-icons.github.io/react-icons/ . It has many icon providers and you also wouldn't face the paid license issue

Comment: I have already add it, if you have looked the file .json. I need some other icons and font awesome have a lot more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow below documentation to install Font Awesome Icon.

https://fontawesome.com/docs/web/use-with/react/

When you're done with the installation, then you can do as an example below to import the fontawesome icons in your function or class components.

```
    import { faCar, faHeart, faShoppingCart } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

class Test extends Component {
render(){
       return (
    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCar} />
)
}
}
```